# Why do java.time.ZoneOffset instances sort 'backwards'?

Tags: java, timezone, timezone-offset

From the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneOffset.html#compareTo-java.time.ZoneOffset-):

> The offsets are compared in the order that they occur for the same time of day around the world. Thus, an offset of +10:00 comes before an offset of +09:00 and so on down to -18:00.

Does anyone know the reason they are ordered this way?  It seems counter-intuitive as it is the opposite of the order of the numerical value of the offset.  It is also the opposite of the order they would appear, reading left-to-right, on a GMT/UTC+0 centred map.

(Aside: I don't understand why the quoted documentation refers to "down to -18:00" either.  -12:00 or -24:00 I'd understand.  Why -18:00?  If you print out the offsets of all the supported `java.time.ZoneId` time zones they range from -11:00 to +12:00.)

UPDATE:  An answer to my aside.  From elsewhere in the same documentation:

> In 2008, time-zone offsets around the world extended from -12:00 to +14:00. To prevent any problems with that range being extended, yet still provide validation, the range of offsets is restricted to -18:00 to 18:00 inclusive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Imagine you've got a list of localized date/times, with the associated timezone, of when some event occurred:

```
(1) 2016/05/26 00:00:00 in Australian Eastern Standard Time (UTC+10)
(2) 2016/05/26 00:00:00 in Greenwich Mean Time (UTC+0)
(3) 2016/05/26 00:00:00 in Japan Standard Time (UTC+9)
```

You can convert these into instants in one single time zone, say GMT:

```
(1) 2016/05/25 14:00:00 GMT
(2) 2016/05/26 00:00:00 GMT
(3) 2016/05/25 15:00:00 GMT
```

and now sort them in order of "which happened first":

```
(1) 2016/05/25 14:00:00 GMT
(3) 2016/05/25 15:00:00 GMT
(2) 2016/05/26 00:00:00 GMT
```

So the Australian time (1) is before the Japanese time (3), which is before the British time (2).

It's just applying the same order to the time zones: as the quote says:

> The offsets are compared in the order that they occur for the same time of day around the world

So Australian Eastern Standard Time is considered "before" Japan Standard Time, which is considered "before" Greenwich Mean Time.

Comment: Of course, another way to see why it is "backwards" is that ]daylight goes "backwards" across the world map too](http://www.yellowpagesoftheworld.com/world/world-map.htm)!

Comment: Very well written Answer. I'll add one more way to think about it: A new day dawns earlier to the east (Earth’s rotation). For example, the Tokyo stock markets open before the London markets, the London markets open before the New York markets which open before the Chicago markets. In ISO 8601 standard used by java.time, we use a Plus sign to represent zones that are ahead of UTC (other time-keepers have used a Minus, by the way). As for left-to-right, that is so only for l-to-r languages and North-on-top maps. Put South on top, or learn Arabic, for a map to read chronologically.